# python : How to add different markers to different Y values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to visualize data where each X value has multiple Y values and I would like to distinguish each Y value visaully. This is the example code

```
xLables = ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']

YValues = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]]
X = [xLables[i] for i, data in enumerate(YValues) for j in range(len(data))]
Y = [val for data in YValues for val in data]

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

When I plot this , I get the following attached

[image]

Each X label has corresponding Y values ... For Ex: A1 has 1,2,3,4 , A2 has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and so on

I have two questions on this one

(1) Can I have different markers for different Y-values .. all 1's are stars , all 2's are diamonds , all 10's are circles ?

something like this may be

[image]

(2) Is there a better way to plot such 2D data and distingush them where each X has multiple Y values

Any suggestions/help is highly appreciated

Thanks

I tried to add markers and different colors , but they apply to all Y values for each X .. but not specific to each Y values..

Comment: Imo the `Y` values are clearly identified w/o markers. By their ordinate in the plot. That is the aim of a scatter plot. Why do you think a marker is needed?

Comment: Edited again...

Answer (score 3):

[image]

My solution is particularly *ad hoc*, but it replicates your target drawing using your data, so that I feel confident posting her here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']
Y2D = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]]

# prepare a dictionary with the characteristics
# we want to change according to the Y value
d = {1:dict(marker="*", s=150, color="red"),
     2:dict(marker="o", s=100, color="yellow"),
     3:dict(marker="o", s= 60, color="blue"),
     4:dict(marker="o", s=100, color="green"),
     5:dict(marker="o", s=100, color="red"),
     6:dict(marker="*", s=150, color="blue"),
     7:dict(marker="o", s=100, color="lightgray")}
# an outer loop on the abscissae and the lists of Y values
for x, ys in zip(labels, Y2D):
    an inner loop on the Y values, plotted separately
    for y in ys:
        # here the point is to unpack the values contained
        # in the "inner" dictionary, addressing the outer by Y
        # zorder=5 places the dots above the grid
        plt.scatter(x, y, ec='k', zorder=5, **d[y])
plt.grid(1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your marker types to list & iterate over them accordingly.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

xLables = ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']

YValues = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]]
X = [xLables[i] for i, data in enumerate(YValues) for j in range(len(data))]
Y = [val for data in YValues for val in data]

plt.scatter(X, Y, marker=matplotlib.markers.CARETDOWNBASE)
plt.grid()

markers=['8','+', '.', 'o', '*','^', 's', 'p', 'h','8','+', '.', 'o', '*','^', 's', 'p', 'h' ]
for i in range(18):
    plt.plot(X[i], Y[i],  marker=markers[i])
    plt.xlabel('X Label')
    plt.ylabel('Y Label') 
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

**Note**: change the order you want accordingly you want. That will be replicated over graphs

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use one plt.scatter() per score.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xLables = [ 'A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']
YValues = [ [1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]]
markers = [ '.', 'o', '^', 'v', '>', '<', '*'] # to be customized
Y = [None for i in range( len( xLables))]

for y in range( len( markers)):
  for x in range( len( xLables)):
    Y[x] = y+1 if y+1 in YValues[x] else None # values start at 1
  if any( Y):  # something to display?
    plt.scatter( xLables, Y, marker=markers[y])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add markers.
A list of them can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html

I think you can use it like this:
`plt.scatter([1, 2, 3]`, marker=11) which means that you'll have to put the values you want to be the same in the same list. I don't think there is a way of giving a list of markers or something like that.

As far as i understand your code would look something like:

```
plt.scatter(X, Y[0], marker=1)
plt.scatter(X, Y[1], marker=1)
plt.scatter(X, Y[2], marker=1)
plt.scatter(X, Y[3], marker=1)
```

You could make this a for loop if it is something having to work for different sizes but i suppose you'll figure it out from here.

Good luck i hope this helps.